# has_one :conditions being interpreted as attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, model-associations

This association:

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one    :map_address, :as=>:addressable, :class_name => 'Address', :conditions => {'addresses.map_address'=>true}, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Causes this error:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :005 > n = Business.new
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :006 > n.build_map_address
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: addresses.map_address
```

The code used to read

```
:conditions => {:map_address=>true}
```

But the lack of table name causes this issue on lookup (it's putting the field name on the wrong table):

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  column counties.map_address does not exist
                                                             ^
SELECT "businesses".* FROM "businesses"   INNER JOIN "addresses" ON ("businesses"."id" = "addresses"."addressable_id" AND "addresses"."addressable_type" = 'Business')  INNER JOIN "counties" ON ("counties"."id" = "addresses"."county_id") AND counties."map_address" IS NULL  WHERE (counties.id = 23)  ORDER BY businesses.updated_at DESC):
```

This option:

```
"adresses.map_address is true"
```

produces this error on lookup:

```
PGError: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "adresses"
LINE 1: ..." ON ("states"."id" = "addresses"."state_id") AND adresses.m...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "businesses".* FROM "businesses"   INNER JOIN "addresses" ON ("businesses"."id" = "addresses"."addressable_id" AND "addresses"."addressable_type" = 'Business')  INNER JOIN "states" ON ("states"."id" = "addresses"."state_id") AND adresses.map_address is NULL  WHERE (states.id = 4)  ORDER BY businesses.updated_at DESC
```

So my question is why is rails trying to turn this condition into an attribute? And how can I make it work both ways? My guess is that rails is trying to set the condition up as a default value for the new record.

Comment: Ok, nevermind, I found that the misinterpretation of the table name was actually coming from searchlogic, so this isn't a rails issue, after all. :(

Comment: So what's the correct code look like?

Answer (score 0):

Is map_attribute a field ? In such case there is an error because you have addresses.map_address, but what addresses object are you talking about ? by writing addresses you are not refering to a specific address
 In other words Map_address seems to be an attribute of an object, so object1 has its map_address, object2 has its map_address, but when you type addresses you are not referring to any object, and it causes an error.

Comment: 4.3.2.4 :conditions

The :conditions option lets you specify the conditions that the associated object must meet (in the syntax used by an SQL WHERE clause). So in this case addresses is a table name

Comment: confirmed that {:addresses => {:map_address => true}} also does not work

Answer (score 0):

why not

```
has_one    :map_address, :as=>:addressable, :class_name => 'Address', :conditions => {:map_address => true}, :dependent => :destroy
```

Comment: that's what it was originally, see question